# React: "Warning: Received NaN for the `children` attribute" when using useReducer

Tags: reactjs

I am learning how to useReducer in React and I am getting this error message when I try to make the states count and number interact with each other: "Warning: Received NaN for the `children` attribute"

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react'

const initialState = {
    count: 0,
    number: 2,
}

const countReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return { count: state.count + state.number }

        case 'DECREMENT':
            return { count: state.count - state.number }

        default:
            return state
    }
}

const Reducer = () => {

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(countReducer, initialState)


    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })}>Increment</button>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' })}>Decrement</button>
            <h1>{state.count}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Reducer
```

The first time I increment, it works fine, it gets incremented or decremented by 2. However, the second time I click, I get that error.

Would someone please tell me why that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't replacing all of your state values when you return from the reducer, so the second time `state.number` is undefined. Then you're trying to do math with undefined which results in the NaN error.

Change this:

```js
return { count: state.count + state.number }
```

To this:

```js
return { ...state, count: state.count + state.number }
```

Do the same for the decrement case.

This is called destructuring, and will copy your previous state into the new object, then you can overwrite whatever needs changed.

Here is the working example:

```js
const {useState, useReducer} = React;

const initialState = {
  count: 0,
  number: 2,
}

const countReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return { ...state, count: state.count + state.number }
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return { ...state, count: state.count - state.number }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const Example = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(countReducer, initialState)
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' })}>Decrement</button>
      <h1>{state.count}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works flawlessly. Would you mind explaining to me why the 'number' state doesn't remain at 2 and goes 'undefined'? That's the only part I don't understand. I mean, why doesn't it keep the initial value of 2 that I am giving it?

Comment: The return value from the reducer function is the new state (the entire new state). It does not merge the return value with the previous values automatically. So if you don't return any piece from the previous state, it's lost. That's why you also have to set the `default` case to return `state`. If you leave that off your whole state will be lost if no matches are found.

Comment: I think people get thrown off because the class-based `setState` **does** merge the new values with old values. But with hooks, neither `useState` or `useReducer` merge, they both require you to replace all pieces of the state when updated.

Comment: The problem I am having now is that I don't how to keep the count going after an API call. In that case, the '...state' syntax won't help. What can I do in that case?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. An API call in and of itself won't effect the state values. Are you doing something with the return values to effect state?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like I was messing something up. After playing around with payload, action, etc., I just got it going a minute ago. Thank you :)